# Auto-Sanitizing illegal PostGIS WGS84 (lat, lon) coordinates

Tags: postgresql, wgs84

I have just stumbled upon what seems to be a very curious behaviour by PostGIS.

The XYZ point `-117.0, 32.0, 0` in [WGS84 (SRID 4326)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System#A_new_World_Geodetic_System:_WGS_84) is legal:

```
items=> SELECT st_y(st_geomfromtext('POINT Z (-117.0 32.0 0)', 4326));
 st_y
------
   32
(1 row)
```

Now consider the XYZ point `32.0, -117.0, 0`. It should be illegal under [WGS84 (SRID 4326)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System#A_new_World_Geodetic_System:_WGS_84), because earth latitudes should be within `[-90, 90], but PostGIS accepts it:

```
items=> SELECT st_y(st_geomfromtext('POINT Z (32.0 -117.0 0)', 4326));
 st_y
------
 -117
(1 row)
```

PostGIS will even calculate the distance between the two illegal points, giving a minor notice:

```
items=> SELECT st_distance_sphere( 
        (st_geomfromtext('POINT Z (32.0 -117.0 0)', 4326)),
        (st_geomfromtext('POINT Z (-117.0 32.0 0)', 4326)));
NOTICE:  Coordinate values were coerced into range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY
CONTEXT:  SQL function "st_distance_sphere" statement 1
 st_distance_sphere
--------------------
   15938523.6399401
(1 row)
```

This caused a very nasty bug with an external library which sanely refused to accept a `-117.0` latitude.

**Can I block PostgreSQL from accepting coordinates violating WGS84 into the DB?**

Comment: Since you clearly know how to perform such a check in a trigger, it appears your question really is, "Can I perform horizon validation at zero cost?" To which the answer is, "No".

Comment: @Vince thanks. I do know how to validate my input, but I thought that PostgreSQL might have a configuration flag that would reject illegal output for me. It is worth mentioning that I only discovered one flaw, and there might be quite a few more.

Comment: There are an infinite number of flaws in data capture, but only a small number that could be automated, and none at no cost. If doing valudation checks reduces input speed from 5000 features/sec to 200 f/s, folks will likely notice.

Comment: You should note that for some values of 4326 your first coordinates are illegal and the second ones are valid. If in doubt don't use 4326

Comment: @Vince The same way I expect floats and integers to be, well, floats and integers, I expect WGS84 Coordinates to be WGS84 Coordinates. Allowing latitude of 117 is the same as allowing division by zero because it saves validation time.

Comment: This is the fundamental distinction between a GEOMETRY and a GEOGRAPHY.  SRID is only carried as metadata, for functions that care -- To a GEOMETRY, 117N is just as valid as -10000 northing in a southern zone UTM oordinate.  You are welcome to code your own competing GEOMETRY implementation from scratch, but you're likely to find that I/O performance matters far more to the general user base than it appears to matter to you.  Human error in data loading is easy enough to check once without increasing the `INSERT` cost for valid values.

Comment: @Vince Would you like to write that last comment, distinguishing GEOGRAPHY and GEOMETRY as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

ok, if i understood this right you want to prevent posttgres to acepting coordinates out of the -90,90 range.

i think you can use a trigger in order to do that

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validate_coordinates()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.coordinates[0] < -90 OR NEW.coordinates[0] > 90 OR NEW.coordinates[1] < -180 OR NEW.coordinates[1] > 180) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Coordinates are not valid or whatever you want to show';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

then you can create your trigger before inserting the points using something like this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER your_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION validate_coordinates();
```

i hope it helps bro